# Has any one used client_side_validations gem with Chosen.js dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). I was wondering if anyone has been able to use chosen select boxes and client_side_validations together.

The issue is that when we use chosen it hides the original select element and renders its own dropdown instead, and when we focus out the validation isn't called and also when the validation message is shown it is shown with the original select element so positioning of the error isnt also correct.

What could be a good way to handle this, My be we can change some code inside `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` which currently looks something like

```
 ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
   unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
   else
     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
   end
 end
```

Any ideas ?

Edit 1:

I have the following solution that is working for me now.

- applied a class "chzn-dropdown" to all my selects that were being displayed by chosen
- used the following callback provided by client_side_validations Gem

```javascript
clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback) {

  if (element.data('valid') !== false) {

    if(element.hasClass('dropdown')){

      chzn_element = $('#'+element.attr('id')+'_chzn');

      console.log(chzn_element);

      chzn_element.append("<label class='message-chzn'>"+message+"</label>");
  }
  else{
    callback();
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add the callback to your app?

Answer (score 1):

About the issue with the validation not running at all when the chosen selection changes you can try this:

```
selectbox.change(function() { setTimeout(function() { selectbox.focusout() }) });
```

I'm still looking for a solution about the validation message positioning because I'd really love to avoid tampering with the client side validations javascript.

**EDIT**:

It seems this is a good solution after all, to keep closer to the client side validations api I came up with the following (*for whom it may concern*):

```
var settings = {
    type: 'ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder',
    input_tag: '<div class="field_with_errors"><span id="input_tag" /><label class="message validationError" /></div>'
};

clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function (element, message, addError) {
    if ($(element).data('chosen') != null) {
        var chosen = $('#' + element.attr('id') + '_chzn');

        clientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings.type].add(chosen, settings, message);

        // Point the label back to the select box
        $('label[for="' + chosen.attr('id') + '"]').attr('for', element.attr('id'));

        // Mark it as invalid
        chosen.data('valid', false);
    } else {
        addError(element, message);
    }
};

clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass = function (element, removeError) {
    if (element.data('chosen') != null) {
        var chosen = $('#' + element.attr('id') + '_chzn');

        clientSideValidations.formBuilders[settings.type].remove(chosen, settings);

        // Un-mark it from invalid
        chosen.data('valid', null);
    } else {
        removeError(element);
    }
};
```

Note that I use a data attribute (`data-chosen`) for initialising select-boxes with chosen. Also for a label click to open chosen to work, I explicitly open the list box on label click:

```
// element is the select box

// Delegate click event from related labels to element (this is already done on "good" browsers)
$('label[for="' + element.attr('id') + '"]').click(function() { element.click() });

// Delegate click event on original element and any related labels to open the list
$(element).click(function() { setTimeout(function() { element.trigger('liszt:open'); }, 0); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback){
    if(element.data("valid") !== false) {
      callback();
      if(element.is("select") && $("#" + element.attr("id") + "_chzn").length > 0){
        element.parent().prepend($("#" + element.attr("id") + "_chzn"));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Tell the gem that you want to validate select tags:

```js
ClientSideValidations.selectors.inputs += ', select';
```

Force validation when Chosen's dropbox changes:

```js
$('#form_field').chosen().change(function(e) {
  var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms[this.form.id];
  $(this).isValid(settings.validators);
});
```

Since Chosen hides the field, you will need to enable validation for that field explicitly in the view:

```rb
<%= form_for ..., :validate => true do |f| %>
...
  <%= f.validate :form_field %>
...
<% end %>
```